# Nuxt.jsで生年月日から年齢を弾き出すプログラムを作ったが表示されない。

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Nuxt.jsとfirebaseを使って道場生の情報として生年月日から年齢を計算するプログラムを作っています。計算まではうまく行きましたが、その計算結果を表示させることがうまくできなくて困っています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Cannot read property 'age' of undefined
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```js
<template>
略
 <td>{{ this.age }}歳</td>
略
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      age: '',
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('setStudentsRef', db.collection('students'));
    // 年齢を計算 //
    const studentRef = db.collection('students');
    studentRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(birthDayDocSnapshot => {
        const birthDay = birthDayDocSnapshot.data().pickerDate;
        const today = moment();
        let y = Math.floor(moment.duration(today.diff(birthDay)).as('months') / 12);
        this.age = y;
      });
    });
  },
```

#### 試したこと

console.log(this.age)とするとちゃんと数字のデータはちゃんと取れています。
コールバック関数の問題でもなさそうですし、どうすればいいのか困っています。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ここにも同様の質問を掲載しています。
https://teratail.com/questions/301462?modal=q-comp

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。this.ageをageとすることで表示がされるようになりました。